# How to find intersections of ranges of float tuples across two lists in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists of the form:

```
lst1 = [(1.2, 4), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]
lst2 = [(1, 3), (6.55, 14.871), (22, 23)]
```

The output I am looking to get is:

```
output = [(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8)]
```

Basically, I want the intersections between the ranges defined by the tuples across the two lists.

You can assume-

1. the indices to be *ordered within a given list*. For example, in lst2:

   ```
   1 < 6.55 < 22
   ```
2. the ranges to be valid (within a tuple, the startVal<=endEndVal). In lst2:

   ```
   1 < 3  and 6.55 < 14.871 and 22 < 23
   ```

What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is with a list comprehension, given that both lists are the same length.

in two lists for readability:

```
# get the min max ranges
a = [(max(i[0], j[0]),min(i[1],j[1])) for i,j in zip(lst1, lst2)]
# check that min is smaller than max
a = [(i,j) for (i,j) in a if i < j]
```

or in one list:

```
a = [(i,j) for (i,j) in [(max(i[0], j[0]),min(i[1],j[1])) for i,j in zip(lst1, lst2)] if i < j]
```

Comment: For the input `lst1 = [(1.2, 4), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]` and
`lst2 = [(1, 3), (6.55, 14.871), (22, 25)]`, the expected output is `[(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8), (24.5, 25)]`. But the output of your program is `[(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8)]`

Comment: No, in the question it is specified: "The output I am looking to get is:
`output = [(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8)]`". The last range is not valid and therefore should not be in the output.

Comment: The ultimate aim is to find the perfect logic to solve the problem. Not to solve it according to a particular use case. The user has clearly stated that `Basically, I want the intersections between the ranges defined by the tuples across the two lists.`.

Comment: @bumblebee, your lists have different number of elements. lst1[2] is (19,21) and lst2[2] is (24.5, 25) so there is no intersection, right?

Comment: Yes, but lst1[3] and lst2[2] intersect, and their intersection is (24.5, 25)

Comment: @Linda the problem with your code is that it only compares i-th element of tuples (since you use zip). So if `lst1` had `(0,0)` as first element instead, it will compare it with `(1,3)` and skip comparison between `(1.2,4)` with `(1,3)` and skip all the other points also - giving you an empty list as the solution, which is not correct

Comment: @bumblebee I get the point. The question should then maybe be clarified: all the ranges declared in one list should be compared to all the ranges declared in the other list. Is that correct?

Comment: @RickyKim I see, I think I misunderstood the question. I thought the aim was a pair-wise comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools` and `heapq.merge`:

```
lst1 = [(1.2, 4), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]
lst2 = [(1, 3), (6.55, 14.871), (22, 25)]

from heapq import merge
from itertools import tee, groupby

m1, m2 = tee(merge(lst1, lst2, key=lambda k: k[0]))
next(m2, None)

out = []
for v, g in groupby(zip(m1, m2), lambda k: k[0][1] < k[1][0]):
    if not v:
        l = [*g][0]
        out.append((max(i[0] for i in l), min(i[1] for i in l)))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8), (24.5, 25)]
```

Comment: This does not find intersection by comparing the two lists but does it by merging which I'm not sure if that's what OP wants. For example, input of `lst1 = [(1.2, 4),(1, 3), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]` and `lst2 = [(6.55, 14.871), (22, 25)]` still outputs the same result, but you might want `[(6.55, 8), (24.5, 25)]` as output instead.

Comment: sry I meant `lst1 = [(1, 3), (1.2, 4), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]`

Comment: @RickyKim Yeah, in this case my script returns `[(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8), (24.5, 25)]`, but it depends on op's input. Maybe ops lists don't have overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using iterators. I use a `while` loop which stays active until both iterators running on the lists are exausthed.

```
lst1 = [(1.2, 4), (5, 8), (19, 21), (24.5, 26)]
lst2 = [(1, 3), (6.55, 14.871), (22, 23)]

itr1 = iter(lst1)
itr2 = iter(lst2)
on1 = True
on2 = True

rng1 = next(itr1)
rng2 = next(itr2)
res = []

while on1 or on2:
    ll = max(rng1[0], rng2[0])
    rr = min(rng1[1], rng2[1])
    if ll < rr:
        res.append((ll, rr))

    if on1 and on2:
        if rng1[0] < rng2[0]:
            try:
                rng1 = next(itr1)
            except StopIteration:
                on1 = False
        else:
            try:
                rng2 = next(itr2)
            except StopIteration:
                on2 = False
    elif on1:
        try:
            rng1 = next(itr1)
        except StopIteration:
            on1 = False
    elif on2:
        try:
            rng2 = next(itr2)
        except StopIteration:
            on2 = False

if len(res) > 1 and res[-1] == res[-2]:
    res.pop(-1)
print(res)
```

Using your sample input, this prints: `[(1.2, 3), (6.55, 8)]`

Answer (score 0):

1. make a simple function to get an intersection range for two range.

```py
    def get_intersect(r1, r2):
            left = max(r1[0], r2[0])
            right = min(r1[1], r2[1])
            if left>right:
                return None
            return (left,right)
```

2. and get all intersections though the double loop

```py
    for i1 in lst1:
        for i2 in lst2:
            ia = get_intersect(i1, i2)
            if ia!=None:
                print(ia)
```

It would be faster, if you add some conditions in the loop.

Comment: "It would be faster, if you add some conditions in the loop." - then you should add them?